# How to make a Multi Login User Using PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 

require_once 'core/init.php';

if(logged_in() === TRUE) {
    header('location: dashboard.php');
}

if($_POST) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username == "") {
        echo "Username Field is Required <br />";
    }

    if($password == "") {
        echo "Password Field is Required <br />";
    }

    if($username && $password) {
        if(userExists($username) == TRUE) {
            $login = login($username, $password);
            if($login) {
                $userdata = userdata($username);

                $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];

                header('location: dashboard.php');
                exit();

            } else {
                echo "Incorrect username/password combination";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Username does not exists";
        }
    }

} // /if


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body class="container">
    <div class = "login-box">
    <img src = "image/person1.png" class = "avatar">
      <h1 id = "login-header">Login</h1>
<form id=registration_form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="form_username" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" />
        <span id="username_error"></span>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="form_password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" />
        <span id="password_error"></span>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value = "Login">
    </div>
        Not yet a member?<a href="register.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;Register</a> 
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me regarding to my PHP. I'm very new in PHP. My website must have a multi-login user. But I try to do it and I failed. I don't received any error. But the problem is when I press the login button nothing happen. If the `user_type` is equal to `admin` I want to link it to adminPanel.php and if `user_type` is equal to `user` I want to link it to userPanel.php. Can somebody fix my code below. I really appreciate it.

```
function login($username, $password) {
    global $connect;
    $userdata = userdata($username);

    if($userdata) {
        $makePassword = makePassword($password, $userdata['salt']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$makePassword'";
        $query = $connect->query($sql);

        if($query->num_rows == 1) {
            $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;

                    header('location: adminPanel.php');       
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;

                    header('location: userPanel.php');
                }
            }

    }

    $connect->close();
    // close the database connection
}
```

Comment: `But the problem is when I press the login button nothing happen`  I don't see any login button, or form code, or code to handle the form.  Also it would be helpful to see the Database schema (structure).  On the surface I would say the only things I see is remove this `$connect->close();` DB is automatically closed, but more importantly add `exit;` after the `header('location: ...)`,  Another important thing is to turn on display errors, and error reporting.  You cannot output anything before header location or it won't work.

Comment: There is not much code here but there is a lot that can go wrong, too much to tell what is (wrong) based on what was provided for the code.  I'll mention it again, put `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the first script called (like index.php) or turn it on in the servers PHP.ini.  Let PHP tell you what the error is, then it will be much easier to tell.

Comment: Lastly security wise, this code is very vulnerable.  The query is not prepared, and your at least not properly checking the password (who knows how you are hashing it). You should use `password_verify` and not put the password in the WHERE condition.  IF user input can go into `$username` such as `$username = $_POST['username']` it would be as simple as `$_POST['username'] = "' OR 1=1 LIMIT 1 --"` to bypass your login checks.  And, one could provide a username and login as anyone, or simply iterate through them by adding the offset to the LIMIT.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Again I'm new in PHP! I don't know everything

Comment: It's ok, I'm not new and I don't know everything.  And some things I did know I forgot now, (like how to use Mysqli)

Comment: I can show you how to fix the issues with `login`, but without the login form, and more context, I'm afraid I can't help with the actual error.

Comment: I already edit this question I put the login form. If I missed something name it

Comment: Yes, but how do you handle the submission, how do you call the `login` function (maybe you misspelled a variable, for example: `$user`, instead of `$username`   What else is in `login.php` (output prevents redirect with header, call exit after calling header)  How do you start the session, ( you can't access $_SESSION if you haven't called session start).  How do you connect to the DB, do you have a good connection. Do you have display errors and error reporting turned on etc... There are many parts to a login form and if any of them are broken, it wont work.

Comment: I hoped this one is right I edit again my question see my login form

Comment: None of this needs to be there after `if($username && $password) {`  except the call to login.  You check if they exist by looking them up in the DB, and you redirect from login.  On top of that you don't call exit after the redirect.  `if($_POST)`  should be `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {`

Comment: can you edit my codes? Didn't work

Comment: Depends what do you mean by `But the problem is when I press the login button nothing happen` exactly.  For example, I consider nothing as the form not doing anything (no submission).  you may consider noting a redirection to `dashboard.php`

Comment: I debated editing this posts title, but they saw the down-votes. I arrived here ONLY because of the "Multi Login" in the title. This is NOT a multi-login question. this is simply a Users Login problem. Further, code so rudimentary that I would hate for a noob to actually decide to follow such architecture. So, Change Title? or Chuck the Lot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Forword**

I feel generous tonight...

This may not fix your issue. As I said in the comments, there are many things that can be wrong.  Without more information on what is happening, how you do things there is no way to tell.

These are things that are important (things to check)

- how you submit the post (the form)

  - fields could be named wrong, form could be setup wrong etc.
  - the form action could simply be wrong
  - the form method could simply be wrong
- how you handle that submission

  - variables could be sent to login() incorrectly, login($password,$username) instead of login($username,$password)
  - vairables could simply be translated wrong, for example you could have `$_POST['user']` insead of `$_POST['username']`
  - you could be doing validation checks on input, which may or may not remove data, could be wrong.
- how you handle starting the session

  - you can't use session until you start it
- what if any output you have when handling the submission

  - output before header location will prevent the redirect
  - header location does not exit the current code scope, stuff after it can run so you should call exit after doing a  redirect.
- how you connect to the DB

  - you may have DB error
- what if any errors you get, what error reporting do you have

  - you could have errors your not reporting for any of the above, and many things I didn't mention.

You probably shouldn't roll you own login system until you have a better handle on the security implications ( and other things).

**Password/Security**

The makePassword function is not included (in your code), but in any case you should use the built in (PHP5.4+)  password function.  It's much more secure and saves a lot of work:

```
function makePassword($plaintext){
    return password_hash($plaintext, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}
```

This will return a 60 char long hash, but it's recommended to use VARCHAR(255).

It will look something like this in the DB:

```
//$2y = BCRYPT (default), $10 Cost or iterations (default), that's all I can remember.
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
```

Then for login (MySqli):

```
//session_start(); //make sure this is called

function login($username, $password, \mysqli $connect) //use type hinting
{   
    //can fail because of syntax errors, missing privileges    
    $stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = ?') OR die($connect->error);
    //can fail because of incorrect number of arguments, invalid types 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username) OR die($stmt->error);
    //can fail for various reasons
    $stmt->execute() OR die($stmt->error);
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $user = $result->fetch_assoc($query);
        if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            header('location: '.$user['user_type'].'Panel.php');
            exit;
        }else{
           //password error
        }
    }else{
       //username error
    }
}
```

Personally I only use PDO these days. It's been several years sense I used MySqli (so forgive me if I got anything wrong here).

For PDO, this is how I connect with it:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$options = [
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
];
try{
   $PDO = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    //only show end user error codes
    die("Error[{$e->getCode()}] connection to DB");
}
```

The options turn on, Exception error reporting and set the default fetch mode to fetch associative array.  With those settings the same thing as above can be done like this:

```
//session_start(); //make sure this is called

function login($username, $password, \PDO $Pdo) //use type hinting
{   
    try{
        $stmt = $Pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute([':username' => $username]);
        if($stmt->rowCount()){
            $user = $stmt->fetch();
            if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                header('location: '.$user['user_type'].'Panel.php');
                exit;
            }else{
               //password error, return an error, or throw an exception etc.
            }
        }else{
            //username error
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        //only show end user error codes
        die("Database Error[{$e->getCode()}]");
    }
}
```

If you notice it takes around 5 calls to MySqi, and PDO takes only 3 calls.  Besides that MySqi is dealing with 3 objects (mysqli, mysqli_stmt, mysqli_result), PDO deals with only 2 (PDO, PDOStatment).  Error reporting is also much cleaner.

A few other notes.

- use `password_hash($plaintext, algo)` to create hashes
- use `password_verify($plaintext, $hash)` to check passwords (note plaintext)
- use `prepared` statements
- Do not lookup by password, it's not a secure way of verifing 2 hashes are the same (casing, encoding etc...)
- use `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION`
- Do not output anything (not even a single space) before using `header`
- call `exit;` after using `header` as it doesn't exit the script it's called in, so it can run code beneath it and produce unexpected results
- avoid using `global` it can be hard to debug your code, instead use dependency injection (pass in the DB connection)
- use DRY principals (Dont Repeat Yourself)

  And there is probably a bunch of stuff I am forgetting.

**UPDATE**

Based on the code you added, the part that handles the form submission can be done like this:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); //unclear
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 

require_once 'core/init.php';

if(true === logged_in()) { //put constant values on the left
    header('location: dashboard.php');
}

if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){ //put constant values on the left

    //ternary condition (shorthand if then)
    $username = empty($_POST['username']) ? false : $_POST['username'];
    $password = empty($_POST['password']) ? false : $_POST['password'];

    //PHP7+ null coalescing can be used instead of above
    //$username = $_POST['username'] ?? false;

    if(!$username) {
        echo "Username Field is Required <br />";
    }

    if(!$password) {
        echo "Password Field is Required <br />";
    }

    if($username && $password) {
        login($username, $password);

        //don't forget the connection, if you use the functions without 
        //it as a global, (which I refuse to use). I once spent a week
        //tracking down changes to a global variable in some code I was fixing, never again.
        // global $connect;
        // login($username, $password, $connect);
    }
}
```

You don't need to do redirects after calling `login` it's already doing them. You don't need to check if the user exists because you are already checking when fetching there saved password. If you need to know that information there you can either throw exceptions (to much to cover) or you can have the login function return them.  In the case that the login is successfule the code will exit before the errors can return.

**Summery**

My best guess, barring any errors (and assuming the session is started) is that this is happening

1. form submission, to self
2. call to login()
3. everything works, call to `header('location: adminPanel.php');`  (with no exit)
4. code returns to the form page (because no exit)
5. call to `header('location: dashboard.php');` And `exit();`

But that is just a guess, because when yo say "when I press the login button nothing happen" that can mean many things.

One of these days I will put a tutorial for something like this on my website, but it will be more comprehensive.

Anyway, hope it helps you.

Comment: That's informative `didn't work at all`, Obviously I can't test any of this as I don't have your Database, nor the will to go that far.  For example I don't even know what you tried as there is so much "wrong".  Not to mention I did say this `It's been several years sense I used MySqli` up front.  To be honest I have no idea if the Mysql part I put before the Update will work, most of that is from PHP.net.  Oh and I forgot to pass in the connection. `global $connect;`  I refuse to use `global`